# Bootstrap thumbnail doesn't print the image retrieved from the database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I am not able to display the image that is retrieved from the folder.

The image was retrieved using product name and id

```
 $q="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id ASC LIMIT 8";
  $res=mysql_query($q);

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $pid=$row[0];
                    $pname=$row[1];
                    $pprice=$row[2];
                    $pcategory=$row[3];
                    $psubcategory=$row[4];
                    $pdetails=$row[5];
                    $pdimg= '<img src="../product_images/'.$pname.'-'.$pid.'.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px"><br>';

  echo "
  <div class=\"col-md-3\">
    <div class=\"thumbnail\">
      <span> $pdimg </span>
      <div class=\"caption\">

        <p>$pdetails</p>
        <p><a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" role=\"button\">Button</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default\" role=\"button\">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>";

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
echo '
  <div class=\"col-md-3\">
    <div class=\"thumbnail\">
      <span>'.$pdimg.'</span>
      <div class=\"caption\">
        <p>'.$pdetails.'</p>
        <p><a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" role=\"button\">Button</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default\" role=\"button\">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>"';
```

I hope this helps you.